# Node.js writeFileSync not writing to files properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

We are experiencing an issue while writing files using Node.js in our web application. Node.js is installed using IISNode.

Everything is working fine on our dev server, but same code is giving problem on our production server (Windows 7, IIS7, Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, Service pack 1).
Basically, on a button click, multiple HTML files are created by node and content is written in them. The problem is that content is not written to all the created files. All files are created but some of the files are left blank with no content.

Here is an excerpt of code that is being used to create and write to files:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(cssData + videoHtml + pageData.content);
let indexFile = fs.openSync(file, 'w+')
fs.writeFileSync(indexFile, $.html(), { encoding: 'utf8' })
fs.closeSync(indexFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const $ = cheerio.load(cssData + videoHtml + pageData.content); 
 fs.writeFileSync(file, $.html(), { encoding: 'utf8' , mode : 0755})
 fs.closeSync(indexFile)
```

Try adding mode in options